# Swapping BB and crankset between bikes

Tags: crankset, bottom-bracket

I have a 2001 DeVinci Santiago road bike, which has a Shimano 105 road triple crankset and an octalink BB. I'm about to buy a 2010 Masi Speciale CX, which has a Truvativ Touro compact double and a square taper BB. Both bikes have a 68mm English-threaded BB shell and 9-speed 105 rear derailleurs.

I'll probably like to swap the cranks, front derailleurs/shifters, chains and BBs between the bikes. Am I correct in assuming that the frames don't care about octalink vs. square taper? Is there any way to remove the BB and crankset simultaneously, without separating them (since I'll be swapping both)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The crank will need to come off the spindle to access the BB tool fitting.

The frames do not care about square vs octalink.

Many frames in the genre the Masi belongs to (short chainstays, large tire clearance) can have trouble playing nice with a 52t ring like on FC-5503/4 due to clearance concerns between the ring and the chainstay. That it's a triple is some consolation because the chainline of the 52 will be a little further out, so it may very well be fine, but it's something to look out for.

Also make sure the FD clamp diameters match for what you're trying to do. The 5500 series FDs had dedicated 28.6 models that wouldn't work if the Masi is 31.8.

Comment: I think the front derailleur is a 30.8mm Shimano FD-R443 (from https://www.bikepedia.com/QuickBike/BikeSpecs.aspx?item=30663 -- not my bike, hopefully didn't change much in 2 years) so I think the diameter won't be a problem.